# HtmlUnit Page response (Downloading File)

Tags: java, json, htmlunit, classcastexception

So im trying to use HtmlUnit to go to a URL but once you visit that url it downloads a json file regarding the data you want. Not sure how to word this but basically in HtmlUnit how can I get the result from a downloaded file.

I suck at explaining here look

trying to check user availability by this

```
private static final String URL = "https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=";
```

...

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL + users[finalUsersIndex]);
```

so that basically creates a new page for each username thing is the URL + username returns a json file of user availability. I know how to read the json file but the problem is this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage
 cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
```

I get that on this line

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL + users[finalUsersIndex]);
```

I suppose I need to create a new page for the response but how would I do that since it automatically downloads file instead of per se, clicking a button which downloads the file. (Correct me if im wrong)

Sorry 4AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name indicates, an HtmlPage is a page containing HTML. JSON is not HTML.

As [the documentation](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#getPage%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow,%20com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest%29) indicates;

> The DefaultPageCreator will create a Page depending on the content type of the HTTP response, basically HtmlPage for HTML content, XmlPage for XML content, TextPage for other text content and **UnexpectedPage for anything else**.

(emphasis mine).

So, as the exception you're getting indicates, the behavior you observed is the documented behavior: you're getting a page that is neither HTML, nor XML, nor text, so you get an [UnexpectedPage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/UnexpectedPage.html).

Your code should thus be:

```
UnexpectedPage page = webClient.getPage(URL + users[finalUsersIndex]);
```

Comment: Ah Im daft. I understand that JSON is not HTML but was wondering what class to use in replacement of HtmlPage. Thank you dude working perfectly.